# One page different displays

Tags: php, html

I was making a simple forum and doesn't know how to display the threads. It was like this. The page will display different displays like the showthread.php any Idea on how to make and people will be able the share the page like "example.com/showthread.php/bla-bla-buh"

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `$_GET` params to make dynamic pages. `example.com/showthread.php?id=123`, then load the correct thread from the database using the ID. If you want pretty URLs, like `example.com/showthread/123` you can look into url rewriting (search for mod rewrite)

Comment: ok thanks for the advice i'll try to do it